# Subset of pandas dataframe whose data type is not consistent

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I have a dataframe that looks like this.
I want to find a subset of this dataframe that's applicable to only 7/31/2018.
7/31/2018 is a datetime object..

How do I subselect the row 2,3,4,5 and stop (not including) 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is still in spreadsheet software so you can use the nrows parameter in read_csv to only read up to that point

```
pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv", nrows=4, skiprows=1)
```

If you want to read in and split by the first fully blank line

```
first_blank_line = df.isnull().all(axis=1).idxmax()
final_df = df.iloc[:first_blank_line]
```

Comment: I want to do this dynamically, and the user(I) does not know where the given sub dataframe stops ahead of time.

Comment: So maybe an idea would be to read it in and then cut it at the first fully blank row? Would that fit the criteria?

Comment: exactly, but I am not sure how to do it yet.

Comment: @JunJang See my edit for an option of how you could do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.iloc`. This allows you to access rows by number. To select rows 2,3,4 and 5, you can simply use

```
df.iloc[[2,3,4,5]]
```

Keep in mind though that rows are 0-indexed, i.e. the first row is `0`.

If you are reading the data with `read_csv()`, you can also use the parameters `skiprows` and `nrows` to specify the rows you want to read:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: I want to do this dynamically, and the user(I) does not know where the given sub dataframe stops ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Is the number of rows between the dates fixed?

If so, you can create a new column with the repeated dates with:

```
dates = df[0][::6].repeat(6)
df['dates'] = dates.values
```

Then you will need to drop the heading rows, either using the fact that they will have null values (if you don't have null values elsewhere) or using the same reasoning I did above about the distance between rows.

After that, you can just filter out what you want by simply doing

```
df[df['dates'] == '7/31/2018']
```